# Setup Storage Spaces or RAID on Windows partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, raid, storage-spaces

I have a 4 years old 500GB Samsung Evo SSD and I'm afraid it could fail, so I'd like to get a new one and setup RAID or Storage Spaces.

I'm curious if I can do the RAID without having to format my current SSD, because I really don't want to reinstall Windows and my apps.

Thanks

Comment: Storage Spaces only works with whole disks. What makes you think your SSD could fail?

Comment: Well it will fail eventually, because they don't last forever, so I'd like to be prepared.

So I can't use Storage Spaces in my casE?

Comment: Everything will fail *eventually*. ;) If you’re afraid of losing data, back it up. *Nothing* can replace backups.

Comment: I do have backups, but I'd like to have something similar to RAID too :)

Comment: It is worth pointing out you cannot use Storage Spaces on the system partition.  If you are worried about hardware failure, setup a hardware based RAID array, and install the OS that provides support for hardware failure(in other words allows you rebuild the array incase a disk in the array fails).